# Ubuntu 12.04 & fglrx 13.1 drivers

Tags: ati, fglrx

My computer has an ATI/AMD Radeon Mobility 4650.

I have attempted to install the drivers as described in [What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx), however the AMD website currently only allows the downloading of the newest drivers, which do not appear to work for 12.04 Precise Pangolin.

I cannot find a mirror with the older releases (12.8 is what I'm looking for), and the information provided in the link above only goes up to 12.8.

I am having a lot of trouble with this, and my video card has lots of overheating issues.  Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.  More info can of course be provided (as long as you let me know what you need!)

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use drivers provided with system?

Comment: I would if I was not having problems with videos and overheating, as described in my post.  :\

Comment: Try to use `ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa` repository and install drivers from there.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install latest drivers from Xorg-Edgers PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fglrx-12
```

And if you want more stable drivers, use `ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/ppa`

Comment: According to the xorg edgers ppa website, they warn about using their ppa with anything over 12.04.2.  It seems that I am running 12.04.4 (recent fresh install a few weeks ago, after reverting from a failed upgrade to 13.x).

Comment: That means you can try.

Comment: I shall give it a shot.  I did what the website suggested and installed xserver-xorg-lts-precise, we'll see.  Thanks!

Comment: Good luck, and if you succeed, do not forget to accept my answer.

Comment: After doing this, my resolution has been lowered to a max of 1152x864 (on a 16:9 display, usually 1600x900).  fglrxinfo gives me the following: X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  135 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (X_GLXQueryServerString)
  Serial number of failed request:  12
  Current serial number in output stream:  12

Comment: Did you run `sudo aticonfig --initial`?

Comment: I did not!  I tried and was given: "aticonfig: No supported adapters detected".  However lspci | grep VGA gives me: 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV730/M96 [Mobility Radeon HD 4650/5165]

Comment: What says `sudo modprobe fglrx`?

Comment: FATAL: Error inserting fglrx (/lib/modules/3.11.0-18-generic/updates/dkms/fglrx.ko): No such device

Comment: Then you should select more older version of the driver. I recommend `fglrx-12`.

Comment: Looks like fglrx-experimental-9, fglrx-experimental-12, fglrx-experimental-13, fgrlx-12, and fgrlx-13.  plus some devel packages and an updater package that is not currently installed.

Comment: If `fglrx-12` fails, the only other option will be `fglrx-experimental-9`.